# Influence of RMSE versus MSE on Convergence of Gradient Descent

Tags: machine-learning, convergence, gradient-descent, loss-functions

I am working in TensorFlow and was wondering if I choosing an MSE loss function would cause different convergence behaviour when compared to a RMSE loss function.

The square root will influence the gradients for sure, but maybe all effects cancel out? Are there good reasons to choose a RMSE loss function over a MSE loss function or vice-versa? I always think that aiming for a linear link between model parameters and loss function is good, to make momentum-based algorithms less confused. If this is true, I think choosing RMSE might have an advantage here.

Any additional thoughts?